# WriteAllBytes OutOfMemory in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an API which returns a file as `byte[]`.
I am trying to download this file onto a local machine using PowerShell (needs to be PowerShell for other automation reasons).
I am using `WriteAllBytes`, however, it throws error with files which are larger than 100MB (I think, threshold might be different).

Are there any other ways to download these files and convert `byte[]` into an actual file?

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
$fileInfo = New-Object ($namespace + ".fileInfoRequest")
$fileInfo.Filename = "$($File)"
$fileInfo.Hash = "e0d123e5f316bef78bfdf5a008837577" #random hash so ignore this.
$FileDetails = $WebService.GetFileInfo($fileInfo)
if ($FileDetails.Exists -eq "True") {
    [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$($InstallPath)\$($File)", $WebService.GetFileData($FileDetails))
} else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "File $($File.FileName) could not be found in the system"
}
```

`$WebService.GetFileData($FileDetails)` returns the file data in byte[] so this is the one that I need to manipulate somehow.

Comment: `WriteAllBytes()` can write hundreds of MB without problem, so I'd suspect the issue is with your API. Which we know nothing about.

Comment: I did think it might be the case but unfortunately I cannot say what exactly the API is and how it's used. All I can say is that it is a web service written in C# (So technically not really an API lol) I will probably need to seek for an advise from the developers who wrote it. Thanks anyways

Comment: `it throws error` - what is "it" and what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same message right this morning.
Weirdly in my case the problem was triggered only when using a remote powershell session, so I can see affinity with API which can be passing trough network as well.
It happened, in my case, that the same command from a "standard" powershell session opened directly on the server console was not raising the error.

I was able to avoid it by using the following on an admin powershell session on the server console:

```
set-item wsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048
```

After that all the remote powershell session stop to give OutOfmemory.